# Restricting the value in Tkinter Entry widget: Why can't I delete the first character?

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

This example successfully allows entry of only numbers, but after the first character is entered, it doesn't allow you do delete it. Why is this happening?

```
import Tkinter as tk

class window2:
    def __init__(self, master1):
        self.panel2 = tk.Frame(master1)
        self.panel2.grid()
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.panel2, text = "Quit", command = self.panel2.quit)
        self.button2.grid()
        vcmd = (master1.register(self.validate),
                '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')
        self.text1 = tk.Entry(self.panel2, validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd)
        self.text1.grid()
        self.text1.focus()

    def validate(self, action, index, value_if_allowed,
                       prior_value, text, validation_type, trigger_type, widget_name):
        if text in '0123456789.-+':
            try:
                float(value_if_allowed)
                return True
            except ValueError:
                return False
        else:
            return False

root1 = tk.Tk()
window2(root1)
root1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because deleting the character would leave you with `""`, which isn't an acceptable entry according to your rules:

```
>>> "" in '0123456789.-+'
True
```

but

```
>>> float("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    float("")
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```